# With Spring / Hibernate, how should this simple business logic be done?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Say I have a simple project with two entities, Account and Transactions, where the Account entity has fields like id, accountName, and transactions, and the Transaction entity has fields like id, description, and amount.

I want to display a simple table that is a list of accounts and the cashflow for a *given* year (i.e. the sum of transactions for a given year). What is the best way to achieve this?

One way is to have a method on the TransactionService like getCashflow(Account account, int year), but this requires this to be called for each account and then the result passed to the model disassociated from the Account.

It seems like the best way would be to have a getCashflow(int year) method on Account, but then how can the sum be performed without using the TransactionService? Or is that how it should be done? How?

I have looked at derived properties, but this isn't a property since it is a result of a given year.

I know this seems a simple problem but I can't work out what the textbook approach is.

Answer (score 1):

Code and code efficiency has direct relation with how you design your tables(entities).

Having `txn ids` in `account` table is not a good idea. It will have lots of unnecessary entries to account tables. Rather having account data in each txn will be better.

Have a look a the design below:
[image]

In the proposed design, you can write your DB query with `SUM` & `GROUP BY` called from  `getCashflow(int year)` on `TransactionService`. You don't have to refer the `Account table` at all from `getCashflow(int year)` making your query more efficient and saving you DB from redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Account has Transactions, and you need list of accounts with some operations(sum) on transactions, so it must be called from `AccountService` with method like `getAccountListWithYearlyCashflow(int year)` and in that method retrieve all possible accounts from `AccountRepository`/datasource and for each account get filtered `transactionList` and perform sum on it.
As the `TransactionService` is dealing with only transactions, it does not make sense having any operation there.
Hope I understand your question correctly :)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. What data type would you use to return the Account associated with a Double? HashMap? Custom 'AccountWithCashflow'? And you would perform query with JPL query?

Answer (score 0):

As Dexter said, it's inefficient to store all the transaction ids in the Account class. It would be better for the Transaction class to be the owning side and reference the Account using account id.

Then, using a TransactionRepository, you can let Spring do the work for you by creating a simple query that finds all transactions in a given year and group this by account ids to find your yearly cashflow.